# How do you change color/image on the default backBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to change color on the default "self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem". To accomplish this I´ve created an custom Button class and implemented it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];    
BackButton *blueSaveButton = [[BackButton alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:blueSaveButton];
temporaryBarButtonItem.title = @"Tillbaka";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;
[temporaryBarButtonItem release];
[blueSaveButton release];
[self gotoLocation];
```

}

But this has no effect at all on the button.
So how do you manage to do this without "breaking" the default/inherited behavior of the navigationbar?

EDIT: The reason is that the button needs to be corporate branded, so default styles will not do.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution (not so good but it works) do this:
1: Implement the button from this tutorial: [www.switchonthecode.com](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-how-to-create-a-blue-navigation-button)

This will override the default behavior of navigationbar.

2: Implement this in every view that needs the custom button:
[osmorphis.blogspot.com](http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/03/trapping-uinavigationbar-back-button.html)

BR

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to be blue (like a Done button) and have the title "Save" you can use one of the built in bar button item types:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(myAction:)] autorelease];
```

Comment: That was fast. I need to set a custom color or image (corporate branded). This is really one heavy downside of iPhone development that this kind of simple task needs heavy customizing of a simple control.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use an image. Create a `UIButton`, set it's title and background image properties using the `setTitle:forState:` and `setBackgroundImage:forState` methods and then create the `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIButton` instance as a custom view. As far as I'm aware, setting a background colour on a button isn't enough.

Comment: I have already done that in BackButton controller. The inference I draw is that NavigationBarItem overrides my custom controller.