# Customize the UINavigationBar backButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am always setting the `backgroundImages` of `UINavigationBars`, but I never worked out how to set the `backgroundImage` of a the back button of a `UINavigationBar`.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to create a custom button for the backBarButtonItem, and then customize it.

If you are looking for tutorials, then go to this question - [How do you change color/image on the default backBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297999/how-do-you-change-color-image-on-the-default-backbarbuttonitem) and I think you find your answer there.

For making a bar button item look like a backBarButtonItem, refer to this answer. [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078/creating-a-left-arrow-button-like-uinavigationbars-back-style-on-a-uitoolbar)

Comment: problem is that I want to keep the 'arrow' shape of it instead of exchanging it for a rectangle..

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,36,30);
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//[button setTitle:@"  Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11]];

[button addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *backbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,36,30);
[backbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backbutton addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backbutton];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Comment: Is this an answer? I've no idea what I'm looking at.