# How to add UIBarButton Programmatically to Programmatically created NavBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am changing my view controller using the following code:

```
 [self.slidingViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FindScoresController" sender:self.slidingViewController];
```

**The segue is PUSH**

Now I want to add `UINavigationBar` Programatically. The code i am using for it is:

```
// Not required if viewController is pushed from previous viewController
UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64)];
UIColor *barColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:82/255.0f green:167/255.0f blue:192/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // iOS 6.1 or earlier
    navbar.tintColor = barColor;
} else {
    // iOS 7.0 or later
    navbar.barTintColor = barColor;

   navbar.translucent = NO;
}
[self.view addSubview:navbar];
```

It adds nav bar successfully.
Now I want to add left and right custom buttons with custom Image.
But I am unable to do so.

Code i am using to add right `UIBarButton` item:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Flip"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(flipView:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
```

But it doesn't show any effect.

I also tried this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

All these code i am writing in `ViewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `UINavigationController`?

Comment: navigationItem is used when your viewcontroller is embedded in a navigation controller. when you setup your own navigation bar you have to use `- pushNavigationItem:animated:`...

Comment: @JakubVano I am using ECSlidingViewController .... and I have navigation controller also

Comment: if you are using a navigationcontroller then you do not have to add your own navigation bar! remove that code and everything should be fine!

Comment: You are setting buttons on item of another bar.

Comment: @AndreSlotta I removed that code...now i hav the navigation bar.. but it shows in all other controllers also I want in only few of them

Comment: you can show or hide the navigationbar in specific viewcontrollers by setting `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES or NO`

Comment: @AndreSlotta Thanx ..now i am getting Flip button..but how can i add custom image to it

Comment: `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage...`

Comment: @AndreSlotta I am using this but how can i add selector to it

Comment: the complete signature includes target and selector: `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatevertheimageisnamed"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(whateverselectoryouwannacall)]`

Comment: @AndreSlotta I am getting default navigation Back buton..can i assign custom image to it

Comment: @AndreSlotta i am using this self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.image  =[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_edit.png"];  but it is not working

Comment: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"]];`

Comment: @AndreSlotta its not working :(

Comment: sorry. this is the code: `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: @AndreSlotta sry to say but this also doesn't respond

Comment: in my case it does. here you can find some more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275724/use-uinavigationbar-appearance-to-change-back-button-image

Comment: @AndreSlotta I am able to change the color of button title but can't able to change title color..how can i do it

Comment: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]};`

Comment: @AndreSlotta thanx a ton...you saved my lots of hours :)

Comment: @AndreSlotta are you there i have a problem... I want to pass a selector name as a parameter..but my app crashes...can you  help